# Super-dense coding protocol with a key

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-information

I have this assignment:

> Show that super-dense coding protocol with the key in the state
>   $\frac{|00⟩⟨00|+|11⟩⟨11|}{2}$ is equivalent (in a sense of
>   transmission rate and security) with classical one-time pad.

I understand that super-dense coding protocol is a *coding protocol*, not an *encryption protocol*, so what exactly is the phrase "...super-dense coding protocol with the **key**..." supposed to mean? How is a key, usually used in encryption protocols, related to this coding protocol? Or has the word key a different meaning here?

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I recommend to read this: http://marozols.wordpress.com/2012/05/23/three-myths-about-quantum-computing-part-3/

Comment: You are correct that superdense coding doesn't relate directly to encryption, so I think the wording of this as "key" is confusing and misleading.  In principle what you're transferring with superdense coding is just a sequence of bits.

I think it was probably asked this way because one of the main contexts in which this might be useful quantum encryption in which two parties are exchanging encryption keys over a quantum channel.

Comment: I also recommend to read the post suggested by Piotr! ;)

Answer (score 2):

I will assume the author means that each party has one qubit of the entangled state

$$\rho=\frac {|00\rangle \langle 00|+|11\rangle\langle11|}{2}$$

Which is interesting because $\rho$ isn't a pure state.

Anyway this state is a "key"; in the sense that without it parties should not make any sense of the data being transmitted.

---

I am not going any further into the details, because of the "homework" tag and the rules we have.

Comment: @YuanJohnJiang A density matrix is representing a pure state iff you can write it as $|\psi\rangle\langle \psi|$. Can you do this for the state in the question?